# Config squid to show ISP external ip

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I've setup a simple squid proxy to connect PCs from internal network to the internet with a 3G modem.
I can only find settings for showing internal client ip or not showing ip at all.

How can I configure squid to show the external ip of the 3G modem?

The squid.conf is no more that:

```
acl test src 192.168.1.3
tcp_outgoing_address 10.43.19.239 test
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
```

Answer (score 0):

Try or adjust with this:

```
# anonymizer options
request_header_access From deny all
request_header_access Server deny all
request_header_access Link deny all
request_header_access Via deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
```